# How to mimic abi.encodePacked in ethers?

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, hardhat

I've got some data that I need to pack into a single `bytes` variable.  In solidity, it looks like this:

```
uint16 id = 42;
address creator = '0x...';
uint256 amount = 1337;

bytes memory message = abi.encodePacked(id, creator, amount);
```

I need to create the same `message` variable on ethers.js, but I can't find the equivalent of `encodePacked` in their docs

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found your solution on the ether.js doc.

It has some functions that would help :

- **ethers.utils.solidityPack( types,values)**
- **ethers.utils.solidityKeccak256(types,values)**
- **ethers.utils.soliditySha256(types,values)**

**Solidity Hashing Algorithms** sections description says

> When using the Solidity abi.packEncoded(...) function, a non-standard
> tightly packed version of encoding is used. These functions implement
> the tightly packing algorithm.

https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/utils/hashing/#utils-solidityPack

Comment: For anyone looking for an example of how to get the keccack256 hash of an encodePacked(address):

`console.log(ethers.utils.solidityKeccak256(["address"], ["<your address>"]));`

Answer (score 2):

In ethers.js, there's a util function can be used https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/utils/hashing/#utils-solidityPack

so what you need to do here is:

```
ethers.utils.solidityPack(["uint16", "address", "uint256"], [id, creator, amount])
```

Answer (score 1):

`abi.encodePacked` simply concats together the variables with no padding or length encoding. The equivalent in Javascript is to convert everything to UIntArry8 and concat those together.

```
const rawMessage = new Uint8Array([
  ...ethers.utils.zeroPad(id, 2),
  ...ethers.utils.arrayify(creator),
  ...ethers.utils.zeroPad(amount, 32)
])
```

or

```
const rawMessage = ethers.utils.concat([
  ethers.utils.zeroPad(id, 2), 
  ethers.utils.arrayify(creator),
  ethers.utils.zeroPad(amount, 32)
])
```

Answer (score 1):

Need to implement this line of code

Solidity:
`keccak256(abi.encodePacked("\x19\x01", domainSeparator, structHash));`

Ethers.js:
`let encodePacked =  ethers.utils.concat([ ethers.utils.toUtf8Bytes('\x19\x01'),  ethers.utils.arrayify(DOMAIN_SEPARATOR), ethers.utils.arrayify(structHash) ])`

`let digest = utils.keccak256(encodePacked)`

Answer (score 1):

A little snippet i made for ethers.js v6

```
     import {ethers} from "ethers"

     function encodePacked(params = []){

        let types = []
        let values = []

        params.forEach(itemArray => {
            types.push(itemArray[0])
            values.push(itemArray[1])
        })

        return ethers.solidityPacked(types, values)
      }
```

***Usage:***

```
encodePacked([
  ["string", "Hello"],
  ["uint256", 100]
])
```